# YOLO - change parameters for multi gpu

Tags: deep-learning, yolo

The goal is to train YOLO with multi-GPU. According to [Darknet AlexeyAB](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-with-multi-gpu), we should train YOLO with single GPU for 1000 iterations first, and then continue it with multi-GPU from saved weight (1000_iter.weigts). So, we don't need to change any parameters in `.cfg` file?
Here is my `.cfg` when I trained my model with single GPU:

```
[net]
# Testing
batch=1
subdivisions=1
# Training
# batch=64
# subdivisions=16
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 500200
policy=steps
steps=400000,450000
scales=.1,.1
```

[AlexyAB](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-with-multi-gpu) says: modify .cfg "if you get Nan". In my case, I'm not getting Nan, but my loss is fluctuating. Shouldn't we change anything when we continue training with multi-GPU? batch? subdivisions? learning_rate? burn_in? We just need to continue training with same configurations?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change `burn_in`, `max_batches` and `steps` between the two cases, for example, if your final target is 500200, your first `.cfg` file should have this:

```
burn_in=100
max_batches = 50000
policy=steps
steps=40000,45000
```

and the second file like this:

```
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 500200
policy=steps
steps=400000,450000
```

You need only to change `learning_rate` if you get a Nan [according to this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-with-multi-gpu), then you should divide `learning_rate` by the number of GPUs and multiply `burn_in` by the same number.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't see any change in your 2nd `burin_in`?. You forgot to change it or something?

Comment: Make first `burn_in` 100.

Comment: Actually by default `burn_in=1000`. So, what you mean is increasing burn_in to 10 times? If `burn_in=1000` with single GPU, with multi-GPU I should change it to `burn_in=10000`?

Comment: Not necessary, when I did this, I used 128 for first one and 2048 for second.

Comment: Could you please explain why we need to increase  `max_batches`?

Comment: When you do the second train using the weight file that generated from the first train, the program consider the number of batches that were done and continue after it, so if you kept the batches with the same number, it will not do any more training.